# Is 'dict', False. Yet gives <type 'dict'>?

Tags: python, types

```
>>> flob = {u'': [u''], u'DL': [u'DL'], u'Gender': [u'Both Sexes'], u'SQ': [u'SQ'], u'BP': [u'BP'], u'Location': [u'World Wide']}

>>> flob is dict

False

>>> flob == dict

False

>>> type(flob)

<type 'dict'>
```

I ask it if its type dict, it says false. I ask it what type it is, it says dict. Why?

Comment: Actually you never ask if it's type is a dict. All of the operations are comparing an instance to a class, which will always be false.

Comment: there's a difference between classes and objects.

Comment: Dan, actually not exactly in python! `isinstance(type(dict), object)` returns True-- i.e., the `type` (a class) is an object.

Comment: +1, to counter the downvotes. The question is clear, explicit, and answers can only help the original poster. Keep them coming, JT.!

Comment: @JT.: please use the "program" mode of StackOverflow, for code; you can either put 4 spaces in front of the code, or have this done automatically with the `{}` button, when you edit the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are comparing the object itself, the instance of `dict`, with `dict`... these two things are different entities. `is` is used to determine if two variable names are pointing at the same object.

```
 type({}) is dict  # returns true.

 a = {}
 b = a
 a is b  # returns true
```

Comment: `istinstance` works with superclasses as well, which may be more well suited than `is`, depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

`is` is used or *identity* comparison.   See below for a hint - `id` returns the memory location of an object and `id(a) == id(b)` is analogous to `a is b`.  For type checks (which should be used sparingly), you want `isinstance`.

```
>>> flob = {u'': [u''], u'DL': [u'DL'], u'Gender': [u'Both Sexes'], u'SQ': [u'SQ'], u'BP': [u'BP'], u'Location': [u'World Wide']}
>>> id(flob)
17665920
>>> id(dict)
8678496
>>> id(flob) == id(dict)
False
>>> type(flob) == dict
True
>>> isinstance(flob, dict)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this orange the same thing as the concept of oranges in general?

Is this orange equal in value to the concept of oranges in general?

What kind of thing is this orange?

Comment: huh? what kind of thing is this answer?

Comment: It's an analogy, meant to draw the OP's attention to the logical fault in a Zen manner. Or were you being ironic?

Comment: Actually, well put, it makes alot of sense. Ta

Comment: +.5 for zen, +.5 for using oranges.

Comment: ok i get it now.  i'm more confused than enlightened when it comes to anything zen ..